# Picker with Data Using Data Binding XAMARIN

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have model `Names` with 2 fields.

```
public class Names

    {
      public string ID { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to get all names from my model `Names` to picker in XAMARIN.

```
    <Picker Title="Select a name" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding AllNames}" 
            ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}" />
```

What is the most simple way to do it?

Comment: Have you actually tried this?  What you have is correct syntax, assuming you have your BindingContext set correctly and have a AllNames property

Answer (score 0):

You would want to create an ObservableCollection with the object you want to use inside your list inside your view model.
Like this:

```
public class ViewModel
{
        ObservableCollection<Names> allNames = new ObservableCollection<GroupedReportModel>();
        public ObservableCollection<Names> AllNames
        {
            get { return allNames; }
            set { SetProperty(ref allNames, value); }
        }
}
```

The SetProperty is an override you will get by adding an implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged onto your viewModel.

The code I use for that looks like this:

```
protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T backingStore, T value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "", Action onChanged = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value))
            return false;

        backingStore = value;
        onChanged?.Invoke();
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        var changed = PropertyChanged;
        if (changed == null)
            return;

        changed.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```